# Can't install tflite-runtime 2.7.0 on Raspberry Pi to work with Lobe

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, tensorflow-lite

I use my Raspberry Pi 3B to run a TensorFlow Lite model I made with Lobe. Python is used to call the [module](https://github.com/lobe/lobe-python) Lobe itself provides. During the last step of the installation for Raspian, which is executing a .sh file, I get the following error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tflite-runtime~=2.7.0 (from lobe[tflite]) (from versions: 2.5.0)
```

I have tried to install this package directly with pip, pip3 and the files from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/tflite-runtime/). I also tried installing Tensorflow in full in the hopes it contains the correct tflite-runtime. I also tried upgrading the existing package, but can't get a higher version than 2.5.0.

Whatever I do, I can't seem to get the correct version. I keep getting the error that Python can't find the Lobe module when executing a script. It does work on my Linux laptop, but not the RasPi. Is there something I'm missing or not interpreting correctly? This is my first project working with models and packages. Please let me know if more info is needed.
The RasPi system info is as follows:

```
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 76.80
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

processor       : 1
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 76.80
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

processor       : 2
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 76.80
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

processor       : 3
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 76.80
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4

Hardware        : BCM2835
Revision        : a02082
Serial          : 00000000dda8ac0e
Model           : Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
```